# Streaming Videos via WebAPI

Tags: asp.net-core, video, asp.net-core-webapi

I want to stream a video via my web API, I use ASP.NET Core. Normally, I would do something like this:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class MyController : ControllerBase
{
     [...]
     public IActionResult Get()
     {     
       return File(System.IO.File.OpenRead("file"), "video/mp4");
    }
 }
```

But the video does not exist at the time of the request, it should be created live. This means, the video does not have a predefined length (should be created as long as the web client requests the video) and its content should be created live.

A simple example would be: I want to have a WebAPI, which returns a video, which always contains the current time. As long as have my browser opened `http://localhost/My/`

I want to see a live video with the current time.

So I have to tasks:

- How do I stream a video with no fixed length?
- How can I create a video live (e.g. draw a string into the video) and return it?

Comment: Look into HLS and DASH.

Comment: Update: Instead of returning a video, a MJPEG stream would also be ok! Does anybody have a working AspNet core WebApi example?